Can we periodically test all external links in DOORS and JIRA to see if they are pointing to nothing, or something different, and ping all watchers?
People are changing requirements outside of DOORS and JIRA, so we end up with links to deleted content and no one is pinged.
Two options to fix, what is possible? :
A. Can we periodically, automatically test all external links in DOORS and Jira, to see if they are pointing to nothing, or something different, and ping all watchers?
or, if not possible,
B. Need to find multiple instances of links to outside DOORS & JIRA, copy files at that link to within DOORS or JIRA, new link, so ping changes!
So if A can't be done ....
Need a script to help find all instances of links to outside of DOORS and Jira, many duplicate, and find a way to make changes to the files they point to, ping everyone pointing to them.  If we need to bring those files into DOORS and Jira, then I need to be able to copy them, then send a list of the links to the new locations back to the folder the files were copied from, so their authors know what they need to update twice.
Needs to be helpful for years to come.  These requirements can be audited a decade+ from now.
Possible individual steps:

Need to find multiple instances of links pointing to requirements files (often Excel and Word) outside of DOORS & JIRA,
Copy the files at that link to within DOORS or JIRA
Create the new link
Send a copy of that new link to the directory where you copied from
Set up to now ping changes, so we are aware of our link now pointing to something different or missing.

Thanks sooooo much!
It's a corporate wide issue.  I need a robust, automated solution.

so, is this a request where you want to find an external company with whom you want to make a contract so that they implement a solution for you?

Hope I don't have to get that complicated...

well, I don't think anyone will program a "corporate wide, robust automated solution that works for years to come" for you for free. If you have specific questions about a single DXL problem, like a command that you don't understand, we can probably help you, but implementing a complete solution is certainly out of scope for stackoverflow.

In both cases in can be scripted to check both scenarios. You did not mention is You are using DOORS Classic or DOORS Next.
In first case You can use DXL to build those scripts and in case of DOORS Next You can use DOORS Widget API to implement widgets (examples of widgets) that will check this.
